# When should you remove authStateDidChangeListener in your iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

When I was creating my app I thought it would be a good general rule to remove every listener I add. However when I added the `authStateDidChangeListener` I couldn't find a good place to remove the listener. I don't think there's ever a time you don't want to be keeping track of the log in state because if you're not logged in you can't access the app (the app is like facebook/instagram so signing in is necessary).

Is it required to remove the `authStateDidChangeListener`? Will never removing it have any consequences?

Comment: There's a great answer by @jnpdx and I am not sure why the question was closed as it's coding related and is not covered in the docs. Question: what happens in the case where the user logs out but the app is still running? Do you still want it to receive events and have a listener hanging around? I would suggest logout is a good please to remove `authStateDidChangeListener`. Otherwise if they log back in you have two, three, four etc. Again though - it depends on the design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not required to remove `authStateDidChangeListener`.

You are correct that it is a good practice to remove unused listeners, but as you outlined, you probably *always* want to know the auth state of your app.

When your app is closed by the system or force closed by the user, its resources will be reclaimed by the system, so there won't be any consequences to not having removed the listener.

All of this, of course, is assuming that you've only created *one* listener and aren't creating a bunch of redundant entities.